# Migrating from strongswan to libreswan

Tags: linux, vpn, strongswan

I have this working strongswan config for IKEv2 with PSK and USER_FQDNs

```json
connections {

    IKEv2PSK {
        remote_addrs = 81.81.81.81
        vips = 0.0.0.0
        version = 2
        dpd_delay = 30
        dpd_timeout = 90
        proposals = aes256-sha256-modp2048

        local {
            auth = psk
            id = @@me@my.comp.any
        }
        remote {
            auth = psk
            id = @@me@my.comp.any
        }
                
        children {
            work {
                remote_ts = 192.168.0.0/24
                inactivity = 3600s
                updown = /usr/lib/ipsec _updown iptables
                esp_proposals = aes256-sha256-modp2048
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and would like to do the same with libreswan. However, I am stuck, the VPN endpoint isn't happy with my secret. This is my ipsec.conf

```
conn work
    ikev2=insist

    left=%defaultroute
    leftsubnet=0.0.0.0/0
    leftid=@me@my.comp.any
    leftmodecfgclient=yes

    right=81.81.81.81
    rightid=@me@my.comp.any
    rightsubnet=192.168.0.0/24

    authby=secret
    mobike=yes
    narrowing=yes
    auto=add
    dpddelay=30
    dpdtimeout=90
    dpdaction=restart
```

ipsec.secrets

```
%any : PSK "thepsk" <-- tried base64 encoding as well here
```

the output

```
$ sudo ipsec auto --up work
181 "work"[1] 81.81.81.81 #1: initiating IKEv2 IKE SA
181 "work"[1] 81.81.81.81 #1: STATE_PARENT_I1: sent v2I1, expected v2R1
002 "work"[1] 81.81.81.81 #1: Received unauthenticated INVALID_KE_PAYLOAD response to DH DH19; resending with suggested DH MODP2048
181 "work"[1] 81.81.81.81 #1: STATE_PARENT_I1: sent v2I1, expected v2R1
182 "work"[1] 81.81.81.81 #2: STATE_PARENT_I2: sent v2I2, expected v2R2 {auth=IKEv2 cipher=AES_CBC_256 integ=HMAC_SHA2_256_128 prf=HMAC_SHA2_256 group=MODP2048}
002 "work"[1] 81.81.81.81 #2: IKE SA authentication request rejected by peer: AUTHENTICATION_FAILED
000 "work"[1] 81.81.81.81 #2: scheduling retry attempt 1 of an unlimited number, but releasing whac
```

Answer (score 0):

oh, forget it. Rubber duck debugging actually works. While writing the question I realized that the identity does not need an `@` prefix when the identity contains an `@` already.

Changing

`leftid=@me@my.comp.any`

to

`leftid=me@my.comp.any`

solves the issue.